# Linearising a $y = -x^2$ graph

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I have been trying to linearise this set of data for a while now. It seems to fit a curve of $y=-x^2$ but I am not sure how to transform it. I have tried $x^2$, $y^2$, $1/x^2$, $\log x$ etc but have had no success. Here is an image of the data set plotted on a graph:

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl9BV.png)

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I want you to try fitting a curve of $e^{ax}+c$.

Comment: Here: http://i.imgur.com/6bucQQb.png

Comment: Having done that, you now transform $y=\ln(x-C)$, where $C$ is the constant in the best-fit curve that you found.

Comment: The graph still seems to be non-linear: http://i.imgur.com/Qs4uDEs.png

Comment: No, I want you to plot $\ln(y-c)$ against $x$...

Comment: oh, apologies. http://i.imgur.com/venvRgS.png still does not seem to be linear

Comment: Could you provide the data points ?

Comment: sure: http://pastebin.com/JCNcf8aZ

Comment: Sorry for the delay ! You did not address the comment to myself (starting your comment by $@Claude Leibovici$ and, so, I was not alerted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the data you provided [here](http://pastebin.com/JCNcf8aZ), I **assumed** the model to be something like $$y=a+b\, e^{cx}$$ which is highly nonlinear withe respect to the parameters as long as $c$ needs to be adjusted. If this is not the case, fix $c$ ata guessed value, define $z_i=e^{cx_i}$ and you just face a linear regression problem. So, for each value of $c$, you have the sum of suares of residuals and, plotting the results, you could identify around which value you get a minimum. This can be easily done using Excel or any linear regression tool.

Since the data do not vary much, we can expect $c$ to be small and run cases. The results, given in the next table,
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 c & SSQ \\
 0.01 & 39.642 \\
 0.02 & 25.243 \\
 0.03 & 14.306 \\
 0.04 & 7.036 \\
 0.05 & 3.033 \\
 0.06 & 1.632 \\
 0.07 & 2.152 \\
 0.08 & 4.015 \\
 0.09 & 6.770
\end{array}
\right)$$ reaveal a minimum close to $c=0.06$; for this value, we have, from the linear regression $a=22.44$ and $b=-0.048$.

So, we have all the required guesses for the parameters and we can start confidently a nonlinear regression. As a result, what was obtained is $$y=22.3916 -0.0411834\, e^{0.0617983 x}$$ Concerning the parameters, 
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 22.3916 & 0.128716 & \{22.1172,22.6659\} \\
 b & -0.0411834 & 0.0131941 & \{-0.0693059,-0.0130608\} \\
 c & 0.0617983 & 0.00362314 & \{0.0540758,0.0695208\} \\
\end{array}$$ tehy are quite significant and we also obtain $R^2=0.9998$ which is very good.

The last table reports your original data as well as the values computed from the correlation.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 x & y & y_{calc} \\
 0 & 22.2213 & 22.3504 \\
 5 & 22.1259 & 22.3355 \\
 10 & 22.1829 & 22.3152 \\
 15 & 22.2114 & 22.2875 \\
 20 & 22.439 & 22.2499 \\
 25 & 22.1171 & 22.1985 \\
 30 & 22.1175 & 22.1286 \\
 35 & 22.0893 & 22.0334 \\
 40 & 21.8352 & 21.9038 \\
 45 & 21.8176 & 21.7271 \\
 50 & 21.6959 & 21.4866 \\
 55 & 21.1582 & 21.1589 \\
 60 & 20.8114 & 20.7126 \\
 65 & 20.2859 & 20.1048 \\
 70 & 19.7753 & 19.2768 \\
 75 & 18.0794 & 18.1491 \\
 80 & 16.3294 & 16.6131 \\
 85 & 13.6814 & 14.5210 \\
 90 & 12.2500 & 11.6714
\end{array}
\right)$$ It is possible that other models give as good or even better results.

Comment: thanks for your very detailed and useful reply—now i have a much better understanding of regression! unfortunately the physics assignment that i was completing required me to transform the data linearly (which is obviously impossible for the type of model that i had). this information is still very useful though, thanks again! p.s apologies for not tagging you in the comment above, I'm very new to this whole stackexchange thing :)

Comment: You are welcome ! Data regression is a very important and interesting matter in almost all possible areas, I would say.